# reactjs app working properly on desktop but not visible on mobile

Tags: mobile, reactjs, desktop-application

I'm new to react and created a small app. Everything works fine on desktop, but the react part of the app doesn't show up on mobile. Can sby tell me what I should do?

http://dry-wildwood-76655.herokuapp.com/

package.json

```
{
  "name": "udacitytransportationapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "prod": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "postinstall": "webpack -p"
  },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.11.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.5.0",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.22.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.13.1",
    "moment": "^2.14.1",
    "offline-plugin": "^3.4.2",
    "react": "^15.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.2.1",
    "react-router": "^2.6.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "^2.5.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Transportation App</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <div class="navbar-brand">TransportationApp</div>
          </div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
              <a href="http://www.bart.gov/">With this app you can search through the BART station schedules</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="container"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

style/style.css

```
.bart-image {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.table-row {
  padding-top:30px;
}
```

Comment: It's not a mobile issue. It also doesn't work in safari

Comment: It does work for me in chrome on desktop, but not in chrome on mobile.

Comment: It doesn't work for me in safari desktop. So it's a library/css issue. What libraries are you using besides react?

Comment: Could you tell me where to look or what to read? This is my first react app and don't really know the environment.

Comment: can you post your package.json file so I can see what you're using? and maybe also your css file

Comment: Updated the question. In the meantime I checked the safari on localhost and the react part didn't show up. So the problem is there both in dev and prod.

Comment: When I inspect your app in safari, I get the error `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: fetch`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is with using fetch. If you look at the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API you can see it is not supported in all browsers. This is why it is showing up in desktop chrome but not safari and why it doesn't work on mobile.